# How do you find out what library you need to import in order to use a class in Java?

Tags: java, maven

A very frequently encountered problem in Java is that let's say you have a question. You search for answer on SO and come across some answer. The answers typically provide code but they don't provide details of what artifacts you need to import in order to be able to use the code in the answer. e.g., I was searching for how to load a json file and parse result into a class in Java and came across the `ObjectMapper`. I can look at its [Javadoc](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html). The Javadoc provides the namespace of the class but again doesn't tell what artifact one needs to import in order to use that class. How do people deal with this problem? It seems there is no structured way. Its just trial and error and doing random searches to find the answer. If I enter the class name or the namespace in Maven repository, very often it does not come up with relevant result. E.g., in case of `ObjectMapper` when I entered `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind` into Maven Central I got [this](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.liferay/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind) which I don't think is the correct artifact. I am asking this question w.r.t. Maven.

Comment: Are you asking about `import` statements? Or are you asking about obtaining a dependency library such as *Jackson*? Your question is not clear.

Comment: `import` statements can be figured out from the Javadoc page. I am asking how do I figure out what dependency I need to add to my `pom.xml`. Has anyone not thought of adding this capability to JavaDoc tool? Why is this not something that is part of JavaDoc documentation for a package?

Comment: @morpheus There is no "official" standard for dependencies in Java. Maven is the un-official standard but there are other options, like Ivy, or no dependency management.

Comment: @aled or Gradle.

Comment: For Jackson specifically you are probably looking for [jackson-databind](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind).

Comment: "*come across some answer*" -> ask the author in a comment, this information would be useful in the answer (often it's not that easy, I know :-/ )

Comment: @DavidConrad I didn't mention Gradle because it doesn't provide its own repository format for dependencies. It is compatible with Maven and Ivy repositories, along with different kinds of remote access protocols to files.

Comment: @aled that's a fair point.

Comment: There is not necessarily a single correct answer to which artifact to use to get a given class.    The advanced search here https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.sonatype.nexus can be very useful.

Answer (score 2):

You are right that there is no standardized way to find out which artifacts you need to use a certain library. Most libraries have at least settled on being distributed through Maven, but there is no standardized process to map classes to artifacts.

Some projects work if you to add a single dependency. Some projects are modular, so you need multiple dependencies for depending on which features you need. Some libraries are split into API and implementations artifacts. Some libraries require different artifacts on certain platforms. You usually can't know how a library is supposed to be setup just by looking at Maven artifacts.

Your best bets it to find the project's (non-javadoc) documentation about how to setup the library and hope that the setup is explained there. Usually that's on the project website or readme file in the repository.

You can however let some else to the dirty work of finding and reading setup instructions for you: ChatGPT or similar tools. You should probably verify that the dependencies are not fake and likely need to correct the version, but generally those tools at good enough at giving you the right information or at least a starting point for further research.

Comment: isn't this a good opportunity for the community? I encounter this problem all the time. And I find myself spending a ton of time trying to figure out exactly what dependency I need to add to `pom.xml` in order to use a class. Searches on Maven Central often yield wrong results just like I showed in my question. I am not expert with build tools and doc generators. I am just a Java developer and feel this is a very common problem for Java developers.

Comment: Maybe but that is outside the scope of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Build dependencies can be quite complex so I doubt that there could be a simple solutions that fits all cases. In the maven world, project documentation can be generated in a somewhat uniform way using the Maven site plugin. It's up to the projects how they structure the content though, so you can't be certain where to find setup instructions.

Comment: You can however let some else do the dirty work of finding and reading setup instructions for you: ChatGPT. I just tried and asked it to give me the maven dependencies that I need if I want Jackson ObjectMapper and it gave me a correct answer (though it didn't use the latest version).

Answer (score 1):

[IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) has a function to find an artifact. When it sees an unknown symbol, one of the solutions is "Search for dependency..."

[image: Search for dependency]

In practice I don't find it to work very well, but maybe it will get better.

There is no relationship between package and Maven's groupId/artifactId. So aside from that, you're just left to do you best detective work on google or GitHub.